# How can I create this specific executable in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: command-line, wine, scripts

So I'd like to run World of Warcraft's `.exe` (`wow.exe`) with the following command from the terminal:

```
__GL_THREADED_OPTIMIZATIONS=1 WINEDEBUG=-all wine wow.exe -opengl
```

The reason for this is because when I launch the game with this, it literally doubles my fps.

Before I could do this so, I need to type the `cd /..path/` in the terminal and then the command above.

Is there any way to make a script for this, so I could launch this with one click or two?

Thanks forward.

Comment: Note you could probably simply execute `__GL_THREADED_OPTIMIZATIONS=1 WINEDEBUG=-all wine /..path/wow.exe -opengl` instead of doing `cd /..path/` and then `__GL_THREADED_OPTIMIZATIONS=1 WINEDEBUG=-all wine wow.exe -opengl`. That single command can be put into a desktop launcher as explained in the link from @mikewhatever. :)

Answer (score 1):

Make a new directory where you want to save your script. I keep my scripts in a directory called `/home/chris/scripts`:

```
$ mkdir /home/chris/scripts
```

Move to the script directory

```
$ cd /home/chris/scripts
```

Create a new file named `wow.sh` using gedit or your favorite text editor:

```
$ gedit wow.sh
```

Add the following to your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /..path/
__GL_THREADED_OPTIMIZATIONS=1 WINEDEBUG=-all wine wow.exe -opengl
```

Save and close the script.

Make the script executable:

```
$ chmod +x wow.sh
```

Ok. Now you've got a script to start WOW in WINE, now you need a desktop launcher which calls the script.

Make a new file which will become your desktop launcher. Use gedit again or your favorite text editor. We'll put this file directly on the desktop.

```
$ gedit /home/chris/Desktop/wow.desktop
```

Add this to the file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon[en_CA]=gnome-panel-launcher
Exec=/home/chris/scripts/wow.sh
Name[en_CA]=World of Warcraft
Name=World of Warcraft
Icon=gnome-panel-launcher
```

Save and close the launcher file.

Make the launcher executable:

```
$ chmod +x /home/chris/Desktop/wow.desktop
```

Double click the launcher and have fun!